# Java Date to MongoDB date with Gson

Tags: java, mongodb, gson

### Introduction

I am currently working on a project that regularly saves several java objects to a MongoDB database.
This object contains a `Date`.

### Problem

The conversion of java Date to Json Mongo give this:

```
new Date() -> "Jan 27, 2022, 2:47:24 AM"
```

But this format does not conform with MongoDB Date.
MongoDB is considered as a string instead of a Date.

### Affected code

```java
 public record DatedPuzzle(Date date, Puzzle puzzle) { 
 }
```

```java
List<InsertOneModel<Document>> bulkWrites = puzzles.parallelStream() 
         .map(puzzle -> new InsertOneModel<>(Document.parse(gson.toJson(puzzle)))) 
         .toList();
```

### Question

***How to create an object conforming to Gson's serialization?***

For example:

```
new Date() -convert with Gson-> "2022-01-27T01:47:24.000+00:00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Gson` object not directly but using `GsonBuilder` and with some configuration, you will achieve the desired result.

***Code:***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(date);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
            .create();

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(date));
}
```

***Output:***

```
Thu Feb 03 23:18:18 EET 2022
"2022-02-03T11:18:18.650+02:00"
```

**UPDATE:**

The disclaimer of the pattern is following:

- `y`   Year (e.g. `12` or `2012`)
- `M`   Month in a year
- `d`   Day in a month
- `h`   Hour of the day, `1-12`
- `m`   Minute in an hour, `0-59`
- `s`   Second in a minute, `0-59`
- `S`   Millisecond in second, `0-999`
- `'`   Escape for text delimiter
- `X` - ISO 8601 time zone (`-08`; `-0800`; `-08:00`)

---

`z` - General time zone (Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00)
`Z` - RFC 822 time zone (`-0800`)

Added some additional codes for a much better understanding of the output on Github.
You could check the locale which is used there simply:

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
```

On my machine it is:

```
en_US
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't know if is a miss take in the output you have `"2022-02-03T11:04:25.766+0200"` but I wanted `"2022-02-03T11:04:25.766+02:00"` the `:` is absent.

Comment: @JavaMan updated answer with new pattern and output

Comment: Can you give more detail about the fonctionement of `.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX")` ?
Beceause when I run it on my computer I obtain `"2022-02-03T00:56:18.650+01:00"` but when I run it on GitHub Workflows I obtain `2022-02-03T11:56:18.650Z`.

Comment: I have the impression that when instead of giving `+00:00` it gives a `Z` instead.

Comment: @JavaMan it corresponds very well. I checked it on my machine - and the result is exactly as it is described in the question. Posted with real output at the answer as well.

Comment: @JavaMan updated the answer a little bit. I have no idea what your application and configuration looks like. However, could give some direction for understanding the output and finding the root of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` classes to convert Date from one representation to another.

[Refer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)